# React App with Jest - Jest encountered an unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test a component using the react-test-renderer library and i'm getting this error. 
[image]

Header.test.js:

```
 import ReactShallowRenderer from "react-test-renderer/shallow";
import React from "react";
import Header from "../../components/Header/Header";

test("should render Header correctly", () => {
  const renderer = new ReactShallowRenderer();
  renderer.render(<Header />);
  // Returning the render output of the jsx
  console.log(renderer.getRenderOutput());
});
```

That's my jest config:

```
"jest": {
"verbose": true,
"transform": {
  "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.(css|scss|less)$": "jest-css-modules"
}
```

My babelrc:

```
{
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    },
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you're importing JSX files as well as .JS? What about importing SVG files? Just making sure you're handling all cases with your transforms.

Comment: Can you post the Header.test.js file. Maybe it has synxtax error.

Comment: Well, i'm not seeing any syntax error, i think that the problem is related to babel.